# Variable references for maintainability/value accuracy

Tags: javascript

I am struggling to think about the correct terminology on a fundamental programming concept.

What do we call the variable/concept of having multiple references to a variable to easily maintain the values or make sure the values are consistent?

**Example**:

```
var strAnimal = 'Fox';

console.log('the quick brown' + strAnimal + 'jumps over the lazy dog')
console.log('A man screaming is not a dancing.' + strAnimal + 'Life is not a spectacle.')
console.log('And maybe... you are a little' + strAnimal + 'with no wings, and no feathers')
```

I keep thinking that it is a constant variable, but I don't think it is correctly called that.

Answer (score 1):

> I keep thinking that it is a **constant variable**

This is actually an oxymoron. "Variable" means "not constant" and "constant" means "not variable". I suspect that you are thinking about **immutability**.

In JavaScript, `var strAnimal = 'Fox';` could be interpreted like so:

1. You **declare** a **variable** called `strAnimal`
2. You **initialize** this variable by **assigning** a string to it

Strings (like all primitive values) are **immutable** in this language, meaning that you cannot alter the integrity of `'Fox'`.

```js
var str = 'bar';

str.split(); // ["bar"]
str.toUpperCase(); // BAR
str.replace('r', 'z'); // baz

console.log(str); // The original string has not changed...
```

On the contrary, objects are **mutable**. See what happens with arrays:

```js
var arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

arr.pop();
arr.shift();
arr.unshift('quux');
arr.push('corge');

console.log(arr); // The original array has changed...
```

Do not think **constants** are **immutable** because, even in ES6, constants are not immutable. They just prevent reassigning. Look at this example:

```js
const obj = {};

obj.foo = 'Foo';
obj.bar = 'Bar';

console.log(obj); // The original object has changed...

obj = 'Baz'; // TypeError
```

To have an immutable constant in this case, you should use `Object.freeze()`:

```js
const obj = {};

Object.freeze(obj);

obj.foo = 'Foo';
obj.bar = 'Bar';

console.log(obj); // The original object has not changed...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the value of a variable, by setting a different value to it directly or let a function operate on it. But you can't change the value of a constant.

Comment: is there a correct terminology behind this? i.e, "a centralized variable to easily change the value and easily maintain" ?